# Topological order fail, AutoEncoder

Tags: sorting, tensorflow, keras, autoencoder, topological-sort

I am getting the following errors when evaluating and fitting my model:

```
2020-11-11 16:08:44.264595: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2
2020-11-11 16:08:44.267135: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2020-11-11 16:08:44.285733: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1640] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 1070 with Max-Q Design major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.2655
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
2020-11-11 16:08:44.285768: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dlopen_checker_stub.cc:25] GPU libraries are statically linked, skip dlopen check.
2020-11-11 16:08:44.287137: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1763] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-11-11 16:08:44.763834: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1181] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-11-11 16:08:44.763859: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1187]      0 
2020-11-11 16:08:44.763865: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1200] 0:   N 
2020-11-11 16:08:44.763991: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1326] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 6798 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1070 with Max-Q Design, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2020-11-11 16:08:51.749906: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/dependency_optimizer.cc:697] Iteration = 0, topological sort failed with message: The graph couldn't be sorted in topological order.
2020-11-11 16:08:51.764509: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/dependency_optimizer.cc:697] Iteration = 1, topological sort failed with message: The graph couldn't be sorted in topological order.
2020-11-11 16:08:51.779508: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:502] layout failed: Invalid argument: The graph couldn't be sorted in topological order.
2020-11-11 16:08:51.893354: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:502] remapper failed: Invalid argument: The graph couldn't be sorted in topological order.
2020-11-11 16:08:51.900916: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:502] arithmetic_optimizer failed: Invalid argument: The graph couldn't be sorted in topological order.
2020-11-11 16:08:51.910006: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/dependency_optimizer.cc:697] Iteration = 0, topological sort failed with message: The graph couldn't be sorted in topological order.
2020-11-11 16:08:51.926004: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/dependency_optimizer.cc:697] Iteration = 1, topological sort failed with message: The graph couldn't be sorted in topological order.
2020-11-11 16:09:42.427153: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/dependency_optimizer.cc:697] Iteration = 0, topological sort failed with message: The graph couldn't be sorted in topological order.
2020-11-11 16:09:42.429043: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/dependency_optimizer.cc:697] Iteration = 1, topological sort failed with message: The graph couldn't be sorted in topological order.
2020-11-11 16:09:42.431491: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:502] layout failed: Invalid argument: The graph couldn't be sorted in topological order.
2020-11-11 16:09:42.444270: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:502] remapper failed: Invalid argument: The graph couldn't be sorted in topological order.
2020-11-11 16:09:42.445833: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:502] arithmetic_optimizer failed: Invalid argument: The graph couldn't be sorted in topological order.
2020-11-11 16:09:42.447143: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/dependency_optimizer.cc:697] Iteration = 0, topological sort failed with message: The graph couldn't be sorted in topological order.
2020-11-11 16:09:42.448878: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/dependency_optimizer.cc:697] Iteration = 1, topological sort failed with message: The graph couldn't be sorted in topological order.
```

The model itself is an autoencoder (getting 512x1 arrays as inputs):

```
# ENCODER
img_width=512
input_shape = (img_width,1)
maxpoolSize=4
    
i = Input(shape=input_shape, name='encoder_input')
x = Conv1D(64, kernel_size=64, activation=activation ,padding='same')(i)
x = MaxPooling1D(maxpoolSize, padding='same')(x)
x = Conv1D(64, kernel_size=32, activation=activation ,padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling1D(maxpoolSize, padding='same')(x)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(128, activation=activation, kernel_initializer=initializer)(x)
bottleneck = Dense(bottleneck_dim, activation=activation, kernel_initializer=initializer, name="bottleneck")(x)

encoder = Model(i, bottleneck, name='encoder')

# DECODER
d_i   = Input(shape=(bottleneck_dim,), name='decoder_input')
x = Dense(128, activation=activation, kernel_initializer=initializer)(d_i)
x = Reshape((128,1))(x)
x = Conv1D(64, kernel_size=32, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling1D(2, padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling1D(4)(x)
x = Conv1D(64, kernel_size=32, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling1D(2, padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling1D(4)(x)
x = Conv1D(64, kernel_size=32, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling1D(2, padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling1D(2)(x)
decoded = Conv1D(1, kernel_size=32, activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)

decoder = Model(d_i, decoded, name='decoder')

# instantiate autoEncoder
autoEncoder_outputs = decoder(encoder(i))
autoEncoder         = Model(i, autoEncoder_outputs, name='autoEncoder')
```

Whenever I evaluate or fit the AutoEncoder the errors rise. This seems strange to me as I do not see any loops in the models. Any one would have an idea about what's going on please ? I am using TF 1.4.1.
Cheers!

edit: When I evalute the encoder alone, the error do not rise. I'm guessing the problem arises from the decoder. I have tried to work on it a bit by removing some layers and still cannot find the source of errors.
edit: Here's what the model looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28Yzv.png)

Comment: The problem is that you are not building your model correctly, you make a Model instance for the encoder but not for the decoder, and then you are reusing the i variable, which you should not do at all.

Comment: Ho I lost that line (decoder = Model(d_i, decoded, name='decoder')) when copy-pasting the code ! I do instantiate the decoder in the actual code. The problem my lie somewhere else. Apologies for the confusion.(The OP is corrected)

Comment: You still are reusing the i variable, you should create a new input layer to build your autoencoder instance.

Comment: I have been trying your solution. Unfortunately it does not solve the error.